# Deployment of jar file and including outside libraries

Tags: java, jar, jdeveloper, mysql-connector

For the past several weeks I've been working with Java and I know that this question may be dumb...

I created a console application which is using the MySQL Connector to update records in a database, the problem is that when I deploy it to a jar file and run it I get that the MySQL Connector is missing. I used JDeveloper for this deployment and from the jar export settings I marked that this library needs to be exported too. I am not sure what could be the issue and any input will be welcomed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you cannot find out if or how JDeveloper can add this to your jar, you can do it yourself with every zip compression tool.

Comment: My problem is more on the side "How to achieve it", at some point I managed to include the library into the jar export, but it still didn't work. The output still said that the library is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add lib: my-sql-connnector.jar in your META-INF.MF in your main jar file.

Comment: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, rather. And it needs to be added to the class-path line.

Comment: No you dont need to add this in your class path, create your jar with jar -cvfm YourJar.jar manifest.mf

Answer (score 0):

Use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) for dependencies. You will build .jar with all dependencies.