# Simple Hello world with PegDown?

Tags: java, markdown

I am recently learning the Java MarkDown library called PegDown. It seems to have many powerful features on top of a pure MarkDown parser. However I have the above exception when I run the following code:

The error occurs at the line `PegDownProcessor pegDown = new PegDownProcessor();`

```

```
import org.pegdown.PegDownProcessor; 


public class Proto1 {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextArea markDownRaw = new JTextArea();    
PegDownProcessor pegDown = new PegDownProcessor(); 

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Proto1 window = new Proto1();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Proto1() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
            ...
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, "flowx,cell 0 0,grow");

    markDownRaw.setText("MarkDown here");
    markDownRaw.setTabSize(4);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(markDownRaw);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Preview");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new buttonActions());
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, "cell 0 1,growx,aligny top");
}

/**
 * button actions for this class 
 * @author yuechuan
 *
 */
private class buttonActions implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //String markDownRawString = markDownRaw.getText();
        //String htmlString = pegDown.markdownToHtml(markDownRawString);
        //System.out.println(htmlString); 

    }

}
}
```

the follow exception occurs when I run the above code

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/parboiled/errors/GrammarException
at org.pegdown.PegDownProcessor.<init>(PegDownProcessor.java:92)
at org.pegdown.PegDownProcessor.<init>(PegDownProcessor.java:71)
at org.pegdown.PegDownProcessor.<init>(PegDownProcessor.java:52)
at org.pegdown.PegDownProcessor.<init>(PegDownProcessor.java:45)
at Proto1$buttonActions.actionPerformed(Proto1.java:81)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.parboiled.errors.GrammarException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 41 more
```

Can anyone give me a hello world example with pegDown ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please download the following jar file http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/parboiled/parboiled-core-1.0.0.jar.zip and add it in your build path. it will solve your problem

Comment: I am still having the same issue. The dependency is already added as shown here

Comment: Which IDE are you using and are you running your program from jar file? if you have packaged your program as jar then check  parboiled-core.jar in your jar file.

Comment: Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567754/deployment-of-jar-file-and-including-outside-libraries/20567869#20567869

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the [pic] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/71v8ipklk3vna4r/Selection_028.png)

Comment: I am using eclipse kepler, and I am not using maven or ant.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture you mentioned in comments, looks like you're missing some dependencies. Here are the ones you need:

- parboliled-core-[version].jar
- parboliled-java-[version].jar
- asm-all-[version].jar

Download links:

- [parboiled-core-[version].jar and parboiled-java-[version].jar](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/downloads)
- [asm-all-[version]](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-all)

Here is a screenshot of the dependencies used: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZkJJ.png`

There is also a blog post that you might find useful:
`https://templth.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/parsing-mardown-with-java/`